# ssh: which side is running the SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH and port forward socks proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/52500/ssh-and-port-forward-socks-proxy)

When I set up a tunnel using dynamic forwarding (ssh -D), which side is running the SOCKS proxy? That is, is the proxy running on the local end (client) or the remote end (server)?

Here's the situation: I want to set up several tunnels chained together using `-L`. Should the `-D` tunnel be the last one in the chain or the first one?

Edit: I found the answer to the second paragraph on Super User (the `-D` tunnel should be at the remotest end). But I'd still like to know where the proxy code is running.

Answer (score 2):

A quick perusal of the OpenSSH sources reveals:

The local `ssh` client handles `-D` very simply, just like all other forwarding sockets: listen locally, push over a channel to the server.

The remote `sshd` server handles all the proxying involved with `SSH_CHANNEL_DYNAMIC`, including decoding SOCKS headers, making outbound connections, and multiplexing the data.